# How do I set AWS credentials using the Google Cloud Composer CLI?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I want to access AWS services from my cloud-composer-managed airflow system.  I don't want to set this up from the airflow UI -- I want to do it using the Google Cloud SDK which serves as the CLI.

Is my only option here to use the CLI's `env-variables` option?  If so, is it sufficient for me to just set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` env varibles?  Or do I need to set lots of airflow-specific connection variables, e.g. for s3 `AIRFLOW_CONN_S3_DEFAULT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tunnel airflow commands through Cloud Composer SDK CLI using [gcloud composer environment run](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/run). For example:

```
gcloud config set composer/location {your-env-location}
gcloud composer environments run {your-env-name} connections -- -a --conn_id your-aws-id --conn_type aws {any other connection details}
```

So if you wanted to update an the `aws_default` connection of an environment called `my-env`, you'd first delete the pre-existing entry (this connection_id is pre-populated by airflow) with the following command:

`gcloud composer environments run my-env connections -- -d --conn_id aws_default`

and then add your credentials as follows:

`gcloud composer environments run data-lake connections -- -a --conn_id aws_default --conn_type aws --conn_extra '{"region_name": "us-east-1", "aws_access_key_id":"YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE", "aws_secret_access_key": "YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE"}'`

Of course, you'll want to update the AWS region name and the creds accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to configure this with the initial `gcloud composer environments create` command?